# Bind a view without extra parameters

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a divider decoration to a Recycler view

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:dividerDirection="@{}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And then I have a BindingAdapter to bind the divider

```
@BindingAdapter("dividerDirection")
    public static void setItemDecoration(RecyclerView view) {
            LineDividerItemDecoration decoration =
                    new LineDividerItemDecoration(view.getContext());
            view.addItemDecoration(decoration);
    }
```

What is the correct way to bind a view without any extra arguments?

If I use something like

```
app:dividerDirection="@{@drawable/line_divider}"
```

It works fine

But it doesn't work with

```
 app:dividerDirection="@{}"
```

I just need a reference to the view in order to get the context

Comment: You need to pass arguments in order to use Binding adapter. I have not seen a way around that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a binding adapter without any parameter.
What you can do is to pass `null`.

`app:dividerDirection="@{null}"`

In this case, your binding adapter could look like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("dividerDirection")
public static void setItemDecoration(RecyclerView view, Integer direction) {
    LineDividerItemDecoration decoration =
                    new LineDividerItemDecoration(view.getContext());
   view.addItemDecoration(decoration);
}
```

**I suggest creating binding adapters with general logic, not having it for every single use-case you have.**

In your case, if you want to provide divider direction, you may pass integer/enum which would have some logic with the parameter.

Comment: Since it's a decoration that I use in every RecyclerView that I have I thought to keep it simple and just remove the parameter so no special consideration is needed and always uses the same size. But nice answer I'll use an enum or something similar :)

Answer (score -3):

recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new LineDividerItemDecoration(this).build());